# Working with userData as a Dictionary

Tags: swift, xcode6, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need my markers to hold a few pieces of data (more than just location, snippet, and title, they are already in use).  I have created a dictionary and then set `marker.userData` as this dictionary.  However, I am having problems getting the values back out of this dictionary.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var mapDict : [String : Bool] = [ "Accredited" : self.accredited,
                             "Accepts Infants" : self.acceptsInfants,           
                           "Accepts Preschool" : self.acceptsPreschool,
                           "Accepts Schoolbag" : self.acceptsSchoolage, 
                               self.slug.last! : false]
marker.userData  = mapDict
```

When I then use

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
    println(marker.userData)
}
```

I get (which is the correct data)

```
{
    "Accepts Infants" = 0;
    "Accepts Preschool" = 1;
    "Accepts Schoolage" = 0;
    Accredited = 0;
    "little-steps" = 0;
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to access each of those values individually to display them to the user.  The problem seems to be that `userData` is an `AnyObject` and not a `Dictionary` (and cannot be downcast as a dictionary, string etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a conditional to get a dictionary out of this,

```
if let dict = userData as? [string:Int] {
    //dict is now a Dictionary
} else {
    // something went wrong with the cast 
}
```

I'm on mobile, sorry for the format.

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  However, just one problem, when printing the values, they always come up as `Optional(1)`.  Which is the correct value, but can I eliminate the `Optional()` part?

Comment: Figured it out, I just used `println(value!)` to return `1`.  Marked this as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict = ["a": true, "b": false]

func f(userdata: AnyObject) {
    print(userdata)
    if let dict = userdata as? Dictionary<String,Bool> {
        print(dict)
    }
}

f(dict)
```

// print

```
{
    a = 1;
    b = 0;
}
["b": false, "a": true]
```